# autohotkey script combining rather than replacing mouse wheels original function

Tags: adobe, autohotkey

I have an AHK script for adobe illustrator that is supposed to replace regular mouse wheel with alt & mouse wheel, but when I roll the mouse wheel it does both the Alt mouse wheel and the regular mouse wheel function. How do I cancel out the original mouse wheel function so that it only executes alt & mouse wheel when i scroll the mouse wheel?

```
#SingleInstance ignore 
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Illustrator.exe

{
;Switches Alt+Wheelup with Wheelup 
wheelup::
Send !{Wheelup} 
Return

;Switches Alt+Wheeldown with Wheeldown 
Wheeldown:: 
Send !{Wheeldown} 
Return
}
```

The original wheel function is to scroll up and down, and alt wheel zooms, so with this script the output ends up as a combo of scrolling and zooming, when I want it to only zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is that, occasionally, some wheelup/downs are firing right as an unseen {alt up} occurs. I also experienced this (using ctrl instead). I then tried using the Hotkey command; it seemed to perform much better, but would still scroll sometimes. What made it work for me was to put a delay before the {alt up}, so that if the hotkey fires again before it finished, it would still be in an {alt down} state.

See if this works for you:

```
wheelup::
Send , {alt down}{wheelup}
Sleep , 100
Send , {alt up}
Return

wheeldown:: 
Send , {alt down}{wheeldown}
Sleep , 100
Send , {alt up}
Return
```